# Are questions only about French language, not its usage are allowed?

Tags: discussion, language, question-quality

For example, I would like to know how French is perceived in English speaking countries. More specifically if most people think it's better to have a native french speaker as a teacher or it's not important.

Comment: The site title includes the word "usage".

Answer (score 7):

I'd be in favour of allowing as wide a variety of questions as is reasonally possible on this site, because I think it is the best way to keep it 'active', so questions about French usage would be fine by me.

I know that this opinion is disputed, though.  I just ask people to bear in mind: what would make a more active community?  An open one where as many questions as possible are accepted (nobody is forced to *answer* a question, after all), or one where many are shut down because they're not the right 'type' of French question?  It's my firm opinion that the Philosophy site suffered in terms of popularity and community because too many questions got shut down too easily.  Let's not make the same mistake with French Language & Usage.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but not your reasons :) I'd keep usage because the name of the site has AND USAGE (seems reasonable to me). Casting nets wide is a worthy objective, but we need to avoid losing focus and becoming a forum-like free-for-all with no coherent identity.

Answer (score 1):

I also take a "broad" view of acceptability. As long as a question is reasonably relevant to the French language, that is ABOUT the language, even if not OF the language, my opinion is that it should be allowed.